# Pageindex is not work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-index-changed

i try in button control:

```
protected void btnImgBack_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
 {
   try
   {
     gdvFile.DataSource = GetFiles();
     gdvFile.DataBind();
     gdvFile.PageIndex=1;
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     throw ex;
   }
 }
```

If `btnImgBack` is click i want to go back in page 1 of grid .But instead of going page 1 i am in same page.`PageIndex` is not work for this or i mistake some thing else?Thanks.

Comment: try to call DataBind after setting the page index, also, replace "throw ex;" with simply throw;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `PageIndex` **before** you `DataBind` the `GridView`.

Comment: @Tim Thanks.I got it.Its a simple mistake but but i spent lot of time for it.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say with so little information, but things to remember:

1. PageIndex is a zero based index therefore PageIndex=1 will set the
   current page to the SECOND page.
2. AllowPaging must be true for PageIndex to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void btnImgBack_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
 {
   try
   {
     gdvFile.DataSource = GetFiles();
     gdvFile.PageIndex=1;
     gdvFile.DataBind();
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     throw ex.Message;
   }
 }
```

this is also assuming that the GetFile() method returns without any errors as well